# Fish Shell Showing /usr/bin/git after every command. Any way to remove this?

Tags: shell, fish

[image: Example of /usr/bin/git]

Been trying to find where this is coming from and I can't seem to figure it out. I know that It's the location of my git install, but not much else. Is it echoing somewhere from some sort of fish config file?

Current theme is Shellder if that's relevant.

edit: https://pastebin.com/BeEdZBrK here is the fish_prompt.fish file

Comment: Please post your `$HOME/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`; add to your question.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Hi added the fish_prompt.fish file

Comment: Where did you get this prompt file? Have you tried switching to a less complicated prompt via the fish config website?

Comment: Looks like it was written for on older version of `fish` where `^` was still a redirection operator.

Comment: See also https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7105. fish is a bit of a moving target. You need to be ready to adapt when they change the syntax.

Comment: thanks everyone! Seems that Shellder as a theme is no longer maintained. Going to look for something to replace it.